# tar command does not list content of tar package with -t option

Tags: linux, command-line, fedora, tar, command-line-arguments

I am trying to list the content of the tar archive with the following command

```
tar -t "filename".tar
```

But the shell works on this one forever without any output message.

I did a research on this and found out that, I should use '-f' option with -t option to list content of archive.

```
tar -tf "filename".tar
```

Can anyone here please answer me why should I use -f option with -t option to list content of archive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can anyone here please answer me why should I use -f option with -t option
>   to list content of archive?

Tar started as a tool to write uncompressed data to a tape drive. (Hence the name, TApe ARchive). This is why it defaults to the tape drive.

On unix-like operating systems devices are treated the same as file. A tape drive might be /dev/st0 (device, SCSI tape 0). This was the **default** input/output for tar.

If you want tar to access another file instead, e.g. /dev/st1 (second tape drive) or /home/my_backup.tar (a *real* file) then you need to specify this with the -f option.

---

Testing this on a modern installation confirm that it still tries to open a SCSI device by default:

```
toad:/home/hennes/demo>tar t demo.tar
tar: Error opening archive: Failed to open '/dev/sa0': No such file or directory
```

Manually specifying a file to open with -f works as expected

```
toad:/home/hennes/demo>tar tf demo.tar
testfile1
testfile2
testfile3
```

Pauls post seem to indicate that this might no longer be the default in all versions of tar. Reading from stdin makes a lot more sense these days, though it breaks with backwards compatibility. For this reason I still prefer the filename `-` to use stdout.

Answer (score 0):

By default `tar` takes its input from stdin - for example, from the output of another command.

The `f` switch tells it to take the input from a file instead.

The proper syntax to use without `f` would be

```
cat filename.tar | tar t
```

(note there is no need for the hyphen with `tar`).  `cat` puts the content of the file in the parameters out to stdout.  The pipe `|` symbol takes stdout and passes it to the next commands stdin.

The reason why `tar` sat there forever was because it was waiting for data to arrive on stdin.